# Is there accepted notation to distinguish $A^2 = \{a^2 \mid a \in A\}$ from $A^2 = \{ab \mid a,b \in A\}$?

Tags: notation, monoid

Let $M$ denote a monoid. Then given a subset $A$ of $M$, we may be interested in one or both of the following subsets of $M$:

$$\{a^2 \mid a \in A\}, \qquad \{ab \mid a,b \in A\}$$

Both could reasonably be denoted $A^2$.

> **Question.** Has anyone ever proposed notation to distinguish these two entities, especially by decorating the notation $A^2$ with further symbols?

Comment: If you need to refer to both at the same time, you could call the second $AA$ and reserve "$A^2$" for the first meaning.

Comment: I think the second is far more common, so if I saw "$A^2$" without any further context I would assume it meant $\{ab\mid a, b\in A\}$. But if you are talking about both, then probably $A^2$ is better notation for the former, and - as Eric says - you should use $AA$ for the latter.

Comment: Right — the problem is, both *are* denoted by $A^2$. However, the second meaning is (I *think*) more common & would be the default interpretation. Evidence for that: with formal languages, which are monoids, both $L^2$ and $LL$ denote the latter & really never the former; with groups $G,H$, $GH$ denotes $\{gh: g\in G, h \in H\}$, so $GG$ follows suit; similarly $G+H$ for e.g. Abelian groups, so $G+G$ denotes the latter, never e.g. $\{g+g: g\in G\}$. If you need both in a document, adopt some convention as @EricWofsey suggests, or denote $\{a^2: a\in A\}$ by $A^{\times\, 2}$.

Comment: More generally, $A^2$ means $A\times A$, namely $\{(a,b):a,b\in A\}$.

Comment: @JohnBentin, that's not really a problem though, because context usually allows us to distinguish $A \times A$ from other uses. Also, worst case scenario we can simply write: $A^{\times 2}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use $A^{\square}$ for the set of squares.  This is common when you want to refer to the set of squares in a finite field.

Comment: That's actually pretty clever!

Answer (score 1):

Without any further warning, I would interpret the notation $A^2$ as the set $\{ab \mid a, b \in A\}$. The reason is that $\mathcal{P}(M)$, the set of subsets of $M$, is a monoid under the multiplication given, for $S, T \in \mathcal{P}(M)$, by
$$
  ST = \{st \mid s \in S, t \in T\}
$$
 and thus the notation $S^2$ is just the square of $S$ in this monoid.

That being said, you may introduce a different meaning for $A^2$ if you give a local definition, but I would rather suggest something like $SQ(A)$ for the set of *squares* of elements of $A$ if there is any risk of ambiguity.